# process out of memory - WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

This is the error I encountered with when I'm running my project in WebStorm 10.0.4

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

My friends who are working with me using the mentioned version of the app does not get the error I get. I also tried with a newer version of the app but did not make any difference.

Comment: I never got that particular error but I did have issues where the IDE would crash often or just lock up for periods of time.  I ended up finding a few options that helped me, you might try them (disclosure: link to my personal/dev blog) https://jwopitz.wordpress.com/2014/11/17/does-webstorm-seem-slow-to-regain-focus-when-switching-between-applications-windows/

Comment: To see what's causing the error, I would recommend you sending your IDE log files (menu Help - Show log) to the WebStorm tech support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us or submitting an issue on the issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB